# Add Go button to apex:enhancedList or to apex:ListViews

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am wonder why when i add `apex:enhancedList`  to my visual force page i cant see the Go button ??
or when I try to  add  `apex:ListViews`   to my visual force page ,

**My question is :**

Why Some times i can see the go button near the select and sometimes not ??
i would appreciate if you can answer  to me .
And if you know how to implement this required ,

Thanks !!!

```
    <apex:ListViews type="Specialty__c"    />

<apex:page standardController="Specialty__c">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script> 
    function getQueryVariable(variable)
    {
           var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
           var vars = query.split("&");
           for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
                   var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                   if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
           }
           return(false);
    }  
    $(document).ready(function () 
        { 
              $("select").val(getQueryVariable("value"));   
        });
 </script> 
<apex:sectionheader title="Specialties" subtitle="Home"   />
<apex:outputPanel >
     <apex:enhancedList type="Specialty__c" height="500"  rowsPerPage="25"  customizable="true"      />   
</apex:outputPanel> 
</apex:page>
```

[image: apex:enhancedlIST]

**the page before override i want it will be like this ....** 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just because it is "the required" (your comment), does not mean it is best practice or makes sense.

This is a time where you:

1. go back to the client, explain the default functionality and how what you are being asked to do does NOT add any additional benefit
2. save the client and yourself some headache.
3. Worst case, use Javascript to change the label of the rendered standard view button from view to go.